# How to Obtain Python Script Return Value to Use in Visual Studio Form?

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I am currently using a DAQC2 PiPlate on my Raspberry Pi and testing Analog Inputs on it. To get the inputs, I call a python script to return them. My problem is that I am using Visual Studio to create a Form GUI so that when the program runs independently on the Pi, the form handles the GUI (running on a 7" touchscreen)

I've currently tried using a StreamReader that reads the script's output every time the timer ticks, which then updates the label afterward.

My PythonScript Class

```
    public PythonScript(string scriptName)
    {
        _scriptName = scriptName;
    }
    public string Run()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "python3";
        psi.Arguments = _scriptName;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = psi;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();

        StreamReader myStreamReader = process.StandardOutput;
        string str = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
        return str;

    }
```

My current work in the Form1.cs class that handles the form loading and the location of the timer

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /**
        //Maximize form to fill screen
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Location = new Point(0, 0);
        TopMost = true;
        Screen currentScreen = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle);
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(currentScreen.Bounds.Width, currentScreen.Bounds.Height);
        **/

        //set up timer
        timer.Interval = (10);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = "";
        PythonScript getValue1 = new PythonScript("/home/pi/Desktop/DAQC2_Script.py");
        value = getValue1.Run();
        label1.Text = value;
    }
```

My python script

```
    import piplates.DAQC2plate as x
    value = str(x.getADC(0, 1))
    return value
```

Currently my form builds and runs properly, however it doesn't do anything. The label remains the default "00.0." I am sure my RaspberryPi and it's equipment are hooked up properly, because I can execute the script (without the return statement) and it reads the data and allows me to print to the console.

I simply want the `value` in the python script to be updated to the `label1.Text` every second. I'm new to not only `c#`, but to python as well so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after awhile of digging, I was drastically overlooking the possibility that my issue was within my python script. I finally got the idea to use process.RedirectStandardError, which led me to find that my 'return' statement was "out of function." Not only was my return statement not in any specific function, but I discovered it wasn't needed at all. The StreamReader handles the reading without any return statement from within the script. This was a learning experience for this noob.